# Add user selections to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, selection

I need to add options from a multiple selection list to an array and ensure that if a user deselects one of the options, it is removed from the array. I've gotten as far as researching the slice and push array methods, but I'm still new to JavaScript. Here's my selection list:

```
<select id="topic" multiple>
    <option value="general">General</option>
    <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
    <option value="question">Question</option>
    <option value="concern">Concern</option>
    <option value="request">Request</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
var values = [];
var select = document.getElementById('topic');
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  values = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < select.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
    var option = select.selectedOptions[i];
    values.push(option.value);
  };

  console.log(values);
});
```

For example: http://jsbin.com/xayuge/1/